# Regex: URL matching doesn't work properly

Tags: regex

I use this regex:

```
<(https:\\/\\/[a-zA-Z\\-]+\\.mydomain\\.com/[a-z0-9\\/\\?\\.\\,_=&]+)>; rel=\"next\"
```

For this one is OK:

```
<https://api.mydomain.com/v1/feeds?page=1559289570000>; rel=\"next\"
```

For this one is failed (no result):

```
<https://api.mydomain.com/v1/feeds/AS7ShjYhsjYHJ89w/likes?page=49771>; rel=\"next\"
```

Do you have any suggestions guys? Thank you very much!

Comment: You are missing uppercase chars in the character class `<(https://[a-zA-Z-]+\.mydomain\.com/[A-Za-z0-9/\?\.,_=&]+)>; rel=\\"next\\"` See https://regex101.com/r/LDD6hv/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did forget `A-Z` in `[a-zA-Z0-9\\/\\?\\.\\,_=&]+`